# Cookie not set when calling API from Sveltekit server action

Tags: cookies, sveltekit

I have a simple ASP.NET API which exposes a login endpoint that returns a session cookie upon succesful authentication. As expected, when I call this API from the client side (Sveltekit application) I receive the cookie and everything works as expected:

```
// +page.svelte
<script>
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        await fetch("http://localhost:5052/auth/login", {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
        })
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
...
</form>
```

Submitting the form sends the request and returns the cookie:
[image: cookie]

The problem occurs when I try to call this login API from a [Sveltekit form action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions):

```
// +page.svelte
<script>
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
<script>

<form method="POST" use:enhance>
...
</form>

// +page.server.ts
import type { Actions } from "./$types";

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ fetch, request }) => {
        await fetch("http://localhost:5052/auth/login", {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
        })
    }
} satisfies Actions;
```

The response from the server action does not contain any `Set-Cookie` header and the client will not receive any cookies. Could somebody tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is being processed in the SvelteKit server, so the browser never gets the cookie. There are probably various valid options:

- Forward the response directly via a [`+server.ts` endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server)
- Forward it via a [hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks)
- Process the response and set cookies in the form action (form actions do not return full `Response` objects, so you cannot just forward the response)

For the last option, it would look something like this:

```js
export const actions = {
    default: async ({ fetch, cookies }) => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5052/auth/login", {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
        });

        // [error handling here]

        const cookie = response.headers.get('set-cookie');
        const token = getCookieToken(cookie); // [implement this]
        cookies.set('session_id', token);
    }
} satisfies Actions;
```

Comment: Very insightful, thank you! Just a question: Would that last approach work for a httpOnly cookie sent from the API, I assume not?

Comment: `httpOnly` just means that you cannot read such a cookie in the browser from `document.cookie`. It should have no effect on the server code (it's a browser instruction).